# Stretch and move normal distribution while keeping the sum 1

Tags: normal-distribution, graphing-functions

I'm currently trying to distribute 100% (1) over 20 points.
So far the standardized gaussian normal distribution did some good work with a standard deviation of 2 and a mean of 10, which distributes roughly 1 (0.999..) over my 20 points: [Looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f12mT.png)

Now, I can just increase the deviation a lot but that doesn't add up to 1 anymore and stops being an equal distribution: [1 is bigger than 20 and the sum is 0.9~.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdD6Y.png)

Is there a way to stretch and move the normal distribution while keeping the sum at 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Translation of mean location does nothing to the sum.
- For the variance we need to scale as follows $\sigma^2 \mathcal{N}(0,t) =\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 t)$

What does the last statement mean? Well, the normal distribution if multiplied by a scalar will automatically adjust the variance to yield a normal distribution so the sum is maintained (this is pretty nice property of a normal distribution)

From the comments it seems you want a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)

So if you want a normal distribution that sums to 1 between a predefined interval then you can use
$$
f(x; \mu, \sigma, a, b) = \frac{\frac{1}{\sigma}N\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}
$$
where the interval is $-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$ and $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative normal distribution.

Comment: What I mean is that I want to keep the interval the same, e.g. over 20 points. If I change the deviation/mean the sum is indeed maintained, just not for [1;20], which is what I'm trying to do.  
For example look at the second graph, how would you display this while keeping the sum at 1?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. So it's $$ \frac{pdf}{cdf - cdf} $$ right? This works pretty good but for whatever reason doesn't seem [standardized (a=1, b=20, deviation=2, mean=10)](http://puu.sh/tiMhU/abd374eeb1.png). I can't find something on google for standardized truncated distributions, am I doing it wrong or am I misunderstanding the formula?

Comment: Well, I just standardized it myself, f(x)/sum of all f(x), its kind of a hack but whatever. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the delay - but if you use the parameters above with a normally distributed value then the sum should converge to one. I mean integrating the function above over $[a,b]$ should yield the denominator. But yes the sum you did should normalize to one by definition but it seems strange.